# Ayuda para un programa en C

Tags: c

Buenas, acabo de escribir un programa en C como prácticas de la universidad el cual debe calcular el coseno de un número mediante la serie de Taylor. El problema es que el programa compila perfectamente pero a la hora de ejecutarlo se detiene justo después del segundo scanf. He probado a usar el depurador ddd pero no parece detectar el problema. El código es el siguiente:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{

    float x, cos=0, t;
    int n, z, r, exp, aux=0, aux2, aux3;

    printf("Introduzca el valor de x(real): ");
    scanf("%f%*c", &x);
    printf("Introduzca el valor de n(natural): ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    while(aux<=n);
    {
        printf("prueba");
        aux3=2*aux;
        r=aux3;
        exp=2*aux;
        t=x;
        aux2=2;
        if(exp==0)
        {
            t=1;
        }

        while(aux2<=exp)
        {
            t=t*x;
            aux++;
        }
        while(aux3>1)
        {
            aux3--;
            r=r*aux3;
        }
    if(aux3==0)
            r=1;
        if(aux%2==0)
        {
            z=1;
        }
        else
        {
            z=-1;
        }

        cos=cos + (t/r)*z;
        aux++;
    }
    printf("cos(%f) = %f\n", x, cos);
}
```

Agradecería mucho que alguien me ayudara pues llevo mucho tiempo buscando el problema y no consigo encontrarlo.

Comment: ¿ No llega a mostrar `"prueba"` ? Y cuando dices *se detiene*, que quieres decir ? algún error por pantalla ? Uso excesivo de CPU y entra en bucle ?

Comment: Sí, entra en bucle porque hay un pequeño error tipográfico, un `;` despeus del `while`.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el **[recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)** y lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**.

Answer (score 5):

Tu problema está en una pequeña línea de código legible:

```
while(aux<=n); // <- El ;
```

El ciclo `while` en cualquier lenguaje de programación, seguido de `;` significa, literalmente:

> *Haz nada mientras la condición sea verdadera.*

Y en tu caso, siempre será verdadera, por lo que se mantendrá en un ciclo infinito *(Para siempre!)*

**La solución:**

Remueve ese `;` al final de esa línea, quedando así:

```
while (aux <= n) 
{
    // Resto del código...
}
```

**EDIT:**

Adicional a ello, encontré que actualizas el `aux` dentro de otro ciclo while, <strike>la verdad no sé como puede afectar en el código como para no mostrar la información al final, pero lo cambié y me funcionó, espero que a tí igual.</strike> del que aún no tengo explicación del por que no muestra el `printf("prueba");` que tienes en el código original, pero he descubierto que en la siguiente línea de código:

```
while(aux2<=exp)
{
    t=t*x;
    aux++;
}
```

Incrementas a `aux` en lugar de `aux2`, y por ello nunca sale de otro ciclo infinito.

Este es el código resultante *(He cambiado algunas cosas porque estaba perdido leyendo, espero sea de agrado para todos. :P)*:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    float x = 0.00f, cos = 0.00f, t = 0.00f;
    int n = 0, z = 0, r = 0, exp = 0, aux = 0, aux2 = 0, aux3 = 0;

    printf("Introduzca el valor de x(real): ");
    scanf("%f%*c", &x);
    printf("Introduzca el valor de n(natural): ");
    scanf("%d[^\n]", &n);

    while(aux <= n) {
        aux3 = 2 * aux;
        r = aux3;
        exp = 2 * aux;
        t = x;
        aux2 = 2;

        if(exp == 0) 
            t = 1;

        while(aux2 <= exp) 
            t = t * x, aux2++; // <- En esta línea exactamente.

        while(aux3 > 1) 
            aux3--, r = r * aux3;

        r = (aux3 == 0) ? 1 : r;
        z = (aux % 2 == 0) ? 1 : -1;
        cos = cos + (t / r) * z;
        aux++;
    }

    printf("cos(%f) = %f\n", x, cos);
    return 0;
}
```

*(A pesar de que la respuesta del programa es erronea, no entra en ningún ciclo infinito)*

Comment: Jeje. Bien visto. ¡ Tengo que volver a graduarme las gafas ! +1

Comment: Entonces, ¿ hay que cerrarla como *error tipográfico* ?

Comment: Pues, creo que sí.

Comment: ¿ Quién le da primero ?

Comment: Adelante, caballero, es toda suya :P

Comment: Muchas gracias por ayudarme! No me había dado cuenta del ';' después del while, pero resulta que lo había puesto porque había intentado hacerlo con un do-while como alternativa, aunque ese no era el problema, sino que que incrementaba aux en lugar de aux2 como bien ha dicho NaCl. Ahora ya está solucionado, me habéis ahorrado muchos dolores de cabeza :D